# How Can I Stop My Mac From Reopening Applications After A Power Failure?

Tags: power

I live in the woods and lose power frequently. When this happens, MacOS tries to restore every application that was open when the power went out. I don't want it to do this. How do i prevent this from happening.

Please note, i am not asking about preventing apps from opening after a restart.

Comment: Would hooking your Mac up to a UPS help avoid this issue completely (I'm assuming you don't have a MacBook of some sort)? A decently sized one could have enough power to keep a Mac running for at least 5-10 minutes.

Comment: A UPS screeching would stress my dog. And i'm typically out of the house when the power fails anyway.

Comment: fair enough. Yeah, unless there was a backup generator that kicked in or a big enough home backup battery, the UPS wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Could you possibly create a program that can detect if the computer is turning back on after a power failure, and if it is then close all the apps? Let me know if this is something you’d want. If you do I can put sometime into developing a simple program to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Hold shift whilst logging in to temporarily disable Resume from re-opening applications.

- Apple KB article: [Automatically re-open windows, apps, and documents on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204005)

Comment: Isn't this the feature that manages restoring apps after a reboot, not a power failure?

Comment: Update: this is for reboots, not power interruptions. Still have not found a way to start to a clean desktop after a power failure.

Comment: @The This should apply to any subsequent login, regardless of how the Mac was shut down and how you were logged out previously. If it’s not working for you that sounds like a bug, what exactly happens when you log in holding shift?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm aware of that will do what you want is disabling ApplePersistence. Unfortunately it has the side effect of disabling versions as well, but perhaps that's a price you're willing to pay.

In `Terminal.app`, type the following, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no
```

To reverse the setting to its default:

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool yes
```